# Beautiful Soup Not Finding Basic HTML Data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from a page using BeautifulSoup. I obtain my HTML data (type: `bs4.element.ResultSet`) and it contains mutliple lines such as the following, which I would like to compile into a list:

```
<td class="va-infobox-label" colspan="1" style="" title="">Weight</td>
```

But when I run a line such as one of those shown below...

```
labels = soup.find_all("va-infobox-label")

labels = soup.find(colspan="1", style="")
```

...I get an attribute error. Alternatively running...

```
labels = soup.find_all("va-infobox-label")
```

...returns a syntax error

What command or tool should I be using if not `find` to obtain all lines containing `va-infobox-label`? My end goal is to obtain a list of labels from this HTML, one of which will be 'weight' as per my example (`title="">Weight<`).

If you need to replicate the error:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

as_val_url = 'https://escapefromtarkov.gamepedia.com/AS_VAL'
as_val_page = requests.get(as_val_url)
as_val_soup = BeautifulSoup(as_val_page.content, 'html.parser')
soup = as_val_soup.find_all(id="va-infobox0-content")

labels = soup.find_all("va-infobox-label")
```

If a glance at the HTML would help you, a public 'beautified' [copy of it is present in my pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YdchrCyd). My example is from line 36.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `soup.select` to search via CSS selectors or `soup.find_all` as below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import StringIO

data = '''
<tr>
    <td class="va-infobox-label" colspan="1" style="" title="">Slot</td>
    <td class="va-infobox-spacing-h"></td>
    <td class="va-infobox-content" colspan="1" style="" title="">Primary</td>
</tr>
<tr class="va-infobox-spacing">
    <td class="va-infobox-spacing-v" colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="va-infobox-label" colspan="1" style="" title="">Weight</td>
    <td class="va-infobox-spacing-h"></td>
    <td class="va-infobox-content" colspan="1" style="" title="">2.587 kg</td>
</tr>
<tr class="va-infobox-spacing">
    <td class="va-infobox-spacing-v" colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="va-infobox-label" colspan="1" style="" title="">Grid size</td>
    <td class="va-infobox-spacing-h"></td>
    <td class="va-infobox-content" colspan="1" style="" title="">5x2</td>
</tr>
'''

f = StringIO(data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
for e in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'va-infobox-label'}):
    print('find_all', e)

for e in soup.select('.va-infobox-label'):
    print('select', e)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, except for anyone in the same position as myself `f = StringIO(data)` was altered to `f = StringIO(str(data))` as of course, I did not have a string-type data set as you get when you use the above example. Much obliged Justin Ezequiel.